# django - filter after slice / filter on queryset where results have been limited

Tags: python, django

having trouble understanding why I can't filter after a slice on a queryset and what is happening.

```
stuff = stuff.objects.all()
stuff.count()
```

= 7

If I then go

```
extra_stuff = stuff.filter(stuff_flag=id)
extra_stuff.count()
```

= 6. Everything is all good and I have my new queryset in extrastuff no issues

```
stuff = stuff.objects.all()[:3]
extra_stuff = stuff.filter(stuff_flag=id)
```

I get the error "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken."

How can I filter further on a queryset where I have limited the number of results?

Comment: What do you need the slicing for?

Comment: the context is I am selecting total games played by a sports team - and then out of those total games I want to have a set of their won games (the slice) which is flagged in a data field called winning team

Comment: In the [QuerySet API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) check out the section on slicing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use `filter()` after you have sliced the queryset. The error is pretty explicit.

```
Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
```

You could do the filter in Python

```
stuff = stuff.objects.all()[:3]
extra_stuff = [s for s in stuff if s.stuff_flag=='flag']
```

To get the number or items in extra_stuff, just use `len()`

```
extra_stuff_count = len(extra_stuff)
```

Doing the filtering in Python will work fine when the size of `stuff` is very small, as in this case. If you had a much larger slice, you could use a subquery, however this might have performance issues as well, you would have to test.

```
extra_stuff = Stuff.objects.filter(id__in=stuff, stuff_flag='flag')
```

Answer (score 7):

Django gives you that error because it's already retrieved the items from the database by that point. The `filter` method is only useful to refine the database query before actually executing it.

Since you're only getting three objects, you could just do the extra filtering in Django:

```
extra_stuff = [s for s in stuff if s.stuff_flag==id]
```

but I wonder why you don't do the filter before slicing.

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel - in this case this actually relate to sports teams. Stuff is the last 3 games played and what I want to work out is out of those 3 games - how many did a team win? Since I am comparing 2 query sets - and won games (extra stuff) must only come from the last 3 games (stored in stuff) I was hoping to slice as doing this in an initial query would be hard

Answer (score 0):

Just made the filtering first after that create another variable and slice it like that:

```
 extra_stuff = stuff.objects.filter(stuff_flag=id)

 the_sliced_stuff = extra_stuff[:3]
```

It works well

Answer (score -3):

Just do 2 queries.

`total_stuff = StuffClass.objects.count()
extra_stuff = StuffClass.filter(stuff_flag=id)[:3]
extra_stuff_count = len(StuffClass.filter(stuff_flag=id))`

Note, if extra_stuff_count is a few count, like 3 or 300.
Because, it's need more memory for more count (in this case, just make one more request).

Comment: This won't work - the OP explains in his comment on Daniel's answer that they want items that have that flag **and** are in the original queryset.

Comment: But this is overhead. Get many rows from DB and manually iteration in memory it's a bad idea.

Comment: Iterating through 3 rows (as in the question) in Python is fine. Your answer might be more efficient but if it gives the wrong answer it's not very useful.

Comment: This is very uneffective

Comment: Agreed. It wasn't the best idea. But it was 3 years ago, be merciful :-D But, regarding the question, we have only two options:

Comment: But, regardless the question, we have only two options for questions like that: 1) Take rows in RAM by one request and then count records with flags. 2) Make 2 queries. Which approach is better depends on a number of rows in the DB and how many rows we are going to get.